# Oracle generates thumbnail based on stored ORDImage

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on an Oracle database application, which needs to generate a thumbnail for each ORDImage stored within IMAGES table.

The procedure I have so far is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE create_blob_thumbnail (p_image_id IN INTEGER) IS
  IMG_ORIGINAL          ORDSYS.ORDImage;
  THUMBNAIL         ORDSYS.ORDImage;
  BLOB_THUMBNAIL    BLOB;

BEGIN

  SELECT IMAGE
  INTO IMG_ORIGINAL
  FROM IMAGES
  WHERE PRODUCT_ID = p_image_id FOR UPDATE;

THUMBNAIL := ORDSYS.ORDImage.Init();

  dbms_lob.createTemporary(THUMBNAIL.source.localData, true);
  ORDSYS.ORDImage.processCopy(IMG_ORIGINAL,
                              'maxscale=128 128',
                              THUMBNAIL);

  -- extract BLOB from OrdImage 
  UPDATE IMAGES
  SET THUMBNAIL = THUMBNAIL.source.localData 
  WHERE PRODUCT_ID = p_image_id;

  dbms_lob.freeTemporary(THUMBNAIL.source.localData);

  COMMIT; 

END;
```

The table structure is given as:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS8dH.png)

When I run the procedure, for example: `"create_blob_thumbnail(5);"`, Oracle returns error at line 16 `"ORDSYS.ORDImage.processCopy(IMG_ORIGINAL,"` saying:

```
"non-existent directory or file for %s operation"
*Cause:    Attempted to access a directory that does not exist, or attempted
           to access a file in a directory that does not exist.
```

Could you please take a look to see where has gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This note:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28414/ch_imgref.htm

Suggests that a Oracle DIRECTORY must be created with relevant permissions for this to work.

However on the same however if you search for the word "thumbnail" you will "Example 3" which I think does what you want to, i.e. creating a thumbnail for an existing image in the database, and updating another column with the thumbnail.